# Update document field in index where source is not stored (_source enabled=false)

Tags: elasticsearch

My use case has a large/complex source document and uses strict mapping with a fairly complex mapping schema.

Due to the number [10's of millions] and size [10KB to 2MB] of the source documents, I do not store **_source** in the index.

The original documents come in different formats: HL7V2 ER7, C-CDA XML and EDI XML, etc).   Those original docs are transformed into JSON representations with the original source stored in S3.  The JSON documents are then indexed (without source) in Elastic.  The JSON is also stored in S3.

I would like to do some trivial mutates to the information stored in Elastic. Primarily for **tagging** use cases. But it seems that, AFAIK, document updates in Elastic require either the entire original source document to be presented or _source stored to effect the mutate/update.

Example: I would like to TAG a subset of documents stored in the Elastic Index. The "tag" field, an array type keyword, could be updated as follows, if source were stored:

```
    POST /my-index/_update/1
    {
      "doc": {
        "tag": ["RED","BLUE"]
      }
    }
```

Again, that update would work properly, provided source were stored. Without **_source** we get the expected (but unfortunate for me) error below:

```
   ...
   "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "document_source_missing_exception",
        "reason" : "[_doc][1]: document source missing",
        "index_uuid" : "SIsgMIeLT_694ATEmHz05g",
        "shard" : "0",
        "index" : "my_index"
      }
    ],
    ...
```

I **really** would prefer not to store _source in the index, as Elastic is handling everything else in my use case, from an ingest/search/performance point of view, just wonderfully.

In a nutshell, I want Elastic to be an *index*, and not, effectively, a *document store+index*.

Is there some API that would allow direct updates to the data in the index, by document? In this case a particular field in the document (e.g., a tag array)??

Cheers for any thoughts.

Comment: The reason the source needs to be stored for updates to work is because an update does a GET first in order to retrieve the current content, then modify it and finally index the new version of the source document. There's no other way unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for that and exactly true. But two points make it kinda interesting, IMO. First, in the case of a 'keyword' field the data is there in the index, even if _source is off. So you _could_ facilitate a mutate with some new value merged into existing value for the field. Second, if I have the new value external and what to update say "ABC" to "XYZ", I don't need the existing source. I'm replacing it in fact.  I'm ready for the answer here to be one of those there's no demand for this functionality and that is why it's not there. Which is fine.